# Eclipse: How do I create a patch where I can include entire files to view in the patch

Tags: eclipse, patch

I tried creating a patch in eclipse. As a common idea when we generate a patch, it only shows the part of the code changed. Is there a way to include the whole file in the patch ?

Comment: Including the whole file defeats the purpose of a patch.  A patch is used to send the minimal amount of data to the system needing patching.

Comment: While creating patch if new file is added then only whole file will be attached else only changes. Why you want the whole file in patch?

Comment: Cozz...project is huge and want to check the functionality of the class and methods involved. Instead of going back to source code..

Comment: @Han usually you apply the patch in separate environment and test it there with debugger and all that stuff. Just looking at it usually is not enough.

Comment: While this can be counter productive to the patching process, I can see how this can be useful in a pre-commit review where we won't having to look up the rest of the source code from the actual file.